# how to add a textbox to a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, textbox

hi I have a C# app that features a canvas. I'd like to programmatically place a textbox (with text) on it. I've tried and tried but all I get is a fully transparent rectangle where my textbox ought to be. is it me or is this a known difficulty?

UPDATE:
I should have mentioned.. (Sorry!) I'm also overriding OnRender in the object to be drawn like so:

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        drawingContext.PushTransform(TransformRotation);
        Draw(drawingContext);
        drawingContext.Pop();
    }
```

and Draw is implemented like so:

```
    public override void Draw(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Rect graphicRectangle = Rectangle;
        ITransform2d transformToDisplay = Layer.TransformToDisplay;
        if (transformToDisplay != null)
        {
            graphicRectangle = new Rect(transformToDisplay.Transform(Rectangle.TopLeft),
                                        transformToDisplay.Transform(Rectangle.BottomRight));
        }
        textBox.Height = graphicRectangle.Height;
        textBox.Width = graphicRectangle.Width;
        Canvas.SetLeft(textBox, graphicRectangle.Left);
        Canvas.SetTop(textBox, graphicRectangle.Top);
    }
```

Comment: Also, why exactly are you doing this?

Comment: @H.B. Yep, our answers didn't make much sense anymore :)

Comment: sorry guys, I seem to have been a bit too quick on posting this

Comment: @mtijn: Does the textBox have a Text set, where is it defined? Also, does changing the graphicRectangle to constants make any difference? Like `textBox.Height = 23`, `Canvas.SetLeft(textBox, 10)`?

Comment: @Meleak: Hey, you got a badge out of it at least :P

Comment: @H.B.: Yeah I noticed :P Never thought I'd see the Disiplined Badge :)

Comment: I had a custom control with a textbox, the custom control was added to the canvas but I forgot to add the textbox so it was left out of the visual tree.. debugging with the constant values also helped me realize a thing or two, thanks, and thanks for the excellent help even though I gave you guys little to go on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas being a panel whose purpose is to arrange and display some kind of content i would recommend that you do not do anything like this.

If you need a Canvas with a TextBox use composition, for example create a `UserControl` with a TextBox over or under the Canvas and expose relevant properties and methods on the UserControl's interface.

---

> Use Panel elements to position and arrange child objects in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx)

Comment: I have to admit, in the end I did exactly this.. kudos to you for being able to provide the answer with such little information!